# Телеграм бот на python по подсчету возраста

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Только учу язык хочу сделать бота ,но совсем не могу понять как
если с таким кодом все работает, то как это правильно интегрировать в бота

```
import datetime

birthdate = input('Enter your birthdate (dd-mm-yyyy): ')
age = (datetime.date.today() - datetime.datetime.strptime(birthdate, '%d.%m.%Y').date()).days // 365
print('You are {} years old.'.format(age))
```

Answer (score 0):

Для начала вам необходимо создать самого бота, как это делать рассказывать не буду, в интернете для этого полно гайдов. Далее стоит установить библиотеку для работы с ботом:

```
pip install pyTelegramBotAPI
```

Далее можете взглянуть на мой пример:

```
import telebot
import datetime

bot = telebot.TeleBot("YOUR_TOKEN")


@bot.message_handler(commands=["help", "start"])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Enter your birthdate (dd-mm-yyyy):")


@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def handle_text(message):
    birthdate = message.text
    age = (datetime.date.today() - datetime.datetime.strptime(birthdate, '%d.%m.%Y').date()).days // 365
    bot.send_message(chat_id=message.chat.id, text='You are {} years old.'.format(age))


bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Не забудте получить токен у [BotFather](https://t.me/BotFather)

Comment: Все сработало, спасибо я ломал голову целый день!